# next.js with firebase hosting: how to create the 404.html file for firebase?

Tags: firebase-hosting, next.js

I am using next.js with Static HTML export, and i want to use firebase for hosting.

The problem is that firebase require a page in the root called 404.html for unknown routes.

Is there a way to generate such page using next.js? or maybe change the firebase hosting behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i found a solution, i added to the firebase.json a rewrite to the error page:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/_error/index.html"
  }
]
```

now, only if the page is not found, firebase will serve the error page as explained here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites

Comment: How do you solve the issue of the rewrite still returning status 200?